# Inserting data from JSON file into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get data about year from JSON files according to my selection from a dropdown box, by an each loop. I want my code to be like this: click on a value year in dropdown box then a table shows up with all the object's values from the file with the same year that was selected.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>Select a YEAR :
      <select id="Selections">
        <option value="year1">year1</option>
        <option value="year2">year2</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="run()">Try it</button>
    <p id="result">    </p>
    <script>
        function run () {
            var x = document.getElementById("Selections").value;
            if (x == "year1") {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "the first year";
                $.getJSON("year1.json", function(json) {
                    $.each(json, function (i,item){
                        $('#tblinfo').append('<tr> <th>'+item.year+'</th>
                            <th>'+item.eposide+'</th></tr>');
                        })
                    });
            } else if (x == "year2") {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "the second year";
                $.getJSON("year2.json", function (json) {
                    $.each(json, function (i,item){
                    $('#tblinfo').append('<tr> <th>'+item.year+'</th>
                        <th>'+item.eposide+'</th></tr>');
                    })
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <table id="tblinfo" border=" 1px solid black" style="width:100%"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JSON files:

year1.json is:

```
[
  {"year":"1995", "eposide":"1"},
  {"year":"1995", "eposide":"2"},
  {"year":"1995","eposide":"3"}
]
```

year2.json is:

```
[
  {"year":"1994", "eposide":"1"},
  {"year":"1994", "eposide":"2"},
  {"year":"1994","eposide":"3"}
]
```

Somehow I can't get any value in the table.

Comment: You cannot have a blank line unless you use template literals - this need to be ONE line `$('#tblinfo').append('<tr> <th>'+item.year+'</th>
              <th>'+item.eposide+'</th></tr>');`

Comment: Any errors thrown in browser console? You have syntax problems but those may be from copy/paste errors

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Do you see the `#result` HTML change?

Comment: hey , in my code it's one line , here is two lines by mistake

Comment: Your code works if it is on one line if I just have the JSON (e.g. load the JSON into a var) - try $.ajax with an error function - there must be an error in the console

Comment: i can't see any error messages , and can't see any reslut but the sentence **the first year**

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean by loading into a var ? i'll drop the GETJSON then ?

Comment: I mean the rest of the code and the parsing works. It must be the getjson that fails:  https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/d35b04ye/  - I need to go to bed

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for the solution , but the file is javascript and i want it json

Comment: You misunderstand. My fiddle works so your code works except the getJSON - so try $.ajax with an error handler instead of getJSON

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    Select YEAR :
    <select id="Selections" onchange="run()">
        <option value="0">choose:</option> 
        <option value="1">year1</option>
        <option value="2">year2</option>
    </select>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <template id="temp">
        <span class="year"></span>
        <span class="episode"></span><br>
    </template>

    <script>
    let url;
    function run(){
        let e=document.querySelector("#Selections");
        let year=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(year==1)url="year1.json";
        else if (year==2)url="year2.json";
        getJson();
    }

    async function getJson() {
        let temp=document.querySelector("#temp");
        let container = document.querySelector("#result");
        let jsonObjects = await fetch(url);
        let items = await jsonObjects.json();
        container.innerHTML="";
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            let clon = temp.cloneNode(true).content;
            clon.querySelector(".year").textContent = item.year;
            clon.querySelector(".episode").textContent = item.eposide;
            container.appendChild(clon);
        });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: @showdev not to mention that this code will only run in the newest browsers

Comment: Sorry about the lack of explanations! I tried to solve the problem using the latest additions to javascript, avoiding jQuery. Works in the new browsers.